# how to fill series color for a chart called from a subreport in java with jasper report

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to change the series color for a chart which is called from a subreport in java with JasperReports

```java
JRChartPlot pl;
JRFillObjectFactory fac;
JRFillChartPlot plot = new JRFillChartPlot(pl, fac);
```

How to instantiate JRChartPLot to my JRFillChartPlot constructor? The previous code gives me null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JRChartPlotFactoryclass and createObject method to instantiate JRChartPlot. May be, this [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Report/jasperreports-2.0.1/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/xml/JRChartPlotFactory.java.htm) might help to understand how to use.

Comment: Im new to jasper report, it will be nice if u can give some code as to how to use it